# Bijection between $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ and $2^{\mathbb N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, cardinals, infinity

Let us define
$$\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}=\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\times\dots$$
I want an explicit bijection between $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ and $2^{\mathbb N}=\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, i.e., the power set of $\mathbb N$

The fact that this bijection exists in not hard to see. It is very clear that $\mathbb {N^N}$ is the same as $[0,1)$ (with an extra decimal point) which is same as $\mathbb R$ (in terms of infinities of course). And we know that the infinities of $2^{\mathbb N}$ and $\mathbb R$ are same.

Also, it's not hard to see that the map $\{a_1,a_2,\dots a_n\}\to (a_1,a_2,\dots a_n,0,0,\dots)$ and $\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}\to (a_1,a_2,\dots)$ gives an idea of a bijection, only that it's not really a bijection since the order matters in ordered pairs, but not in sets.

Some other ideas are available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360428/mathbb-n-mathbb-n-2-mathbb-n) as well. But, what I want is a well constructed (*nice* if possible) bijection between $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ and $2^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: One way to (almost) construct such a function is to use the facts that there is (almost) a nice bijection between $2^{\Bbb N}$ and $[0,1]$ (binary decimal expansion), and there is also (almost) a nice bijection between $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ and $[0,1]$ ([continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've already given an example of how to construct a bijection between the two. I will be a bit of a contrarian and show that there is no constructive bijection between the two.

A constructive bijection $f : \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to 2^\mathbb{N}$ means (roughly) that if I give you a sequence $s \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and a number $n$, you can actually compute the $n$th element of the sequence $f(s)$. And conversely, you should actually be able to compute the $n$th element of $f^{-1}(t)$ given some $t \in 2^\mathbb{N}$.

The problem here is that it can be shown that any constructive function $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to 2^\mathbb{N}$ must be continuous when giving $\mathbb{N}$ and $2$ the discrete topology and taking the $\mathbb{N}$-ary product, and any constructive function $2^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ must also be continuous.

This means that any bijection between the two must be a homeomorphism.

But the problem is that $2^\mathbb{N}$ is well-known to be compact, while $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is not compact.

Thus, there can be no homeomorphism between the two, and hence no constructive bijection.

In fact, there can be no constructive surjection $2^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, since this would be a continuous surjection and therefore $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ would be compact.

The intuition behind the continuity requirement is that if I have a continuous function $f : 2^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and I wish to compute the $n$th element of $f(s)$, I should be able to do so after looking at only a finite number of terms in the sequence $s$. This implies continuity.

Comment: What topologies are you putting on $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: @Dionel Jaime For the set $A^\mathbb{N}$, I'm giving $A$ the discrete topology and $A^\mathbb{N}$ the product topology $\prod\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A$.

Comment: Ok, so you're using Tychonoff? Very interesting. I am curious about this fact about a constructive map having to be continuous.

Comment: @DionelJaime You should look into Brouwer's version of real analysis with constructive logic. He basically adds two axioms. The first is that $2^\mathbb{N}$ is compact. The second is that every function $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is continuous. Any constructive function can be defined solely using constructive logic, hence can be defined using constructive logic + Brouwer's two axioms. And it turns out that in models of Brouwer's intuitionism, every definable function $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ actually is continuous.

Comment: @DionelJaime I know there's a classic result in Bishop-style constructive mathematics that 'every function is continuous' (see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164694/are-all-functions-in-bishops-constructive-mathematics-continuous ); I presume the argument is some variation on that.

Comment: I am not much familiar with this dicrete topology arguments, but the result was quite nice!

Comment: What about a constructive bijection between $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $n^{\mathbb{N}}$ [where n is a natural greater than two.]?

Comment: @Math There is a bijection between $2^\mathbb{N}$ and $n^\mathbb{N}$. The key is to consider binary encodings of numbers $1..n$. Read only enough bits from the input sequence to specify the first element of the output sequence, and use the remaining bits to construct the rest. For instance, take $n = 3$. If the input sequence starts with a $0$, the first element of the output sequence is $2$. If the input starts with $11$ or $10$, the first element of the output sequence is 3 or 1 respectively.

Comment: @MarkSaving If I understand correctly a possible encoding for 6 is $0-00;1-01;2-100;3-11;4-1011;5-1010$

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: @Math Yes, that's one way to do it. In retrospect, an easier way might be to encode $n$ as a string of $n - 1$ zeroes and encode $i < n$ as a string of $i$ zeroes followed by a 1. No binary required for that method.

Answer (score 0):

One (almost as noted in a comment above) bijection is to go between binary and continued fractions for numbers in $[0,1)$.  See [Minkowski question-mark function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function) for more information.